# Angular: $event is not object

Tags: angularjs

I got this error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined at Scope.$scope.dispatchAction.

I can't figure out what is the problem, would you please help me? Thanks.

***----Template----***

```
$templateCache.put("template/dropdown-user.html",
    '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">'+
        '<li ng-repeat-start="item in items">'+
            "<a ng-click=\"click(item,$event)\" ng-href=\"{{item.link}}\"><i class=\"fa fa-{{item.icon}} fa-fw\"></i> {{item.label}}</a>"+
        '</li>'+
        "<li ng-repeat-end class=\"divider\" ng-if=\"item.isDivider\"></li>"+
    '</ul>'
    );
```

***---Directive---***

```
.directive('navbarMenuUserItem',[function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template/dropdown-user.html',
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            items: '=',
            click: '&itemClick'
        }
    }
}])
```

***---HTML---***

```
<navbar-menu-user-item item-click="dispatchAction(obj,event)" items="usermenu"></navbar-menu-user-item>
```

***Controller****

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl',
['$scope','$sanitize','$log','$location','dashboardService','AuthService',
    function($scope, $sanitize, $log, $location, dashboard,AuthService){

        $scope.messages = dashboard.getMessages();
        $scope.usermenu = dashboard.getUserMenu();
        $scope.sidebarmenu = dashboard.getSidebar();

        $scope.logout = function(){
            AuthService.logout();
            $location.path('/');
        };

        $scope.dispatchAction = function(obj,event){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(obj);
        };


    }
]);
```

Comment: @KhanhTO, I just added the $, but still no luck, thanks.

Comment: You're using wrong syntax to call scope function binding. Try `<a ng-click=\"click({obj:item,event:$event})\"` in your template dropdown-user.html

Comment: I think that both obj and event here are undefined, can you just log them without any operations? `item-click="dispatchAction(obj,event)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Khan TOs suggestion is correct. You have to bind your item and your event to the scope in which your expression `item-click` should be evaluated.

Alternativly you could change your isolated scope definition in the directive to:

```
scope:{
        items: '=',
        click: '=itemClick'
    }
```

And your `item-click` attribute in the HTML to:

```
item-click="dispatchAction"
```

In this way you bind your `dispatchAction` function directly to a variable in your directives scope.